# How can I access master page control from my content page?

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<li id="Adduser"><a href="AddAgent.aspx">Add User</a></li>
```

this html code is in master page . and I want to use this `id="Adduser"` in my
content page which is link with this master page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Add runat="server" in

tag to make it server control

```
<li id="Adduser" runat="server" > <a href="AddAgent.aspx">Add User</a></li>
```

Then

```
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;  
HtmlGenericControl MyliTag ;        // Use using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

mpContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

MyliTag = ( HtmlGenericControl)  mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("Adduser");
```

Now you can change  Properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"`, then you can find the control with `FindControl`.

```
<li id="Adduser" runat="server"><a href="AddAgent.aspx">Add User</a></li>
```

Code behind on the aspx page

```
HtmlGenericControl li = Master.FindControl("Adduser") as HtmlGenericControl;
li.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"EditAgent.aspx\">Edit User</a>";
```